# Enable Outlook Web Add-in only on the Web

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-js

I developed an Outlook web-based add-in. To install it, I added the manifest file from the "Manage add-ins" page in OWA: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142256.aspx. The add-in is showing up in both Outlook Web App and Windows Desktop App.

Is there a setting or code change need to be done to make the add-in available only in the Web App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have no such capability - we'd like the platform to provide users with consistent experience regardless of Outlook client/platform they use. Would you mind sharing why would you like your add-in to show up in OWA but not in desktop Outlook?

Comment: I have already developed an Add-in for desktop Outlook and is working fine.  Now, I'm trying to use Office.js API to develop Web Add-in but It seems this API could not do all old features. Until We get all features in next releases, our company decided to use a Web Add-in only on the Web and keep using the old Add-in only on desktop app. So now, I get useless add-in (the web one) in the desktop app.

Comment: Could you elaborate on which features you need but are missing? Understanding the gab between the two will help a lot, either by allow us to provide an alternative way of doing something or by giving priority to features developers are using in COM/VSTO.

Comment: I have developed Add-in in OWA using on-send event feature. If I deploy this add-in, then it is also available in Desktop which is not working because the on-send event in Desktop is different with the one in OWA.

Comment: Our plugin is only showing in OWA and not desktop version of Outlook but cannot figure out why

Answer (score -1):

I guess now it's possible. If you insert **VersionOverrides** in the manifest file an leave it empty, then the outlook client will not show the app but the outlook on the web client will show the app.

Example:

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
   <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            </ExtensionPoint>
      </DesktopFormFactor>
    </Host>
    </Hosts>
```

Don't forget the namespace:
`xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides"`

Comment: I dont get how leaving `VersionOverrides` empty but in the example it's not, could you explain what exactly can be moved out of `VersionOverrides`?