# How to hide/disable an add-in in outlook but keep it on OWA?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We are developing an Outlook Web App add-in.
Our Client dont want to see the add-in in outlook, in other words, they want to show the enabled add-in in owa only. is it possible to do that?
or is it possible to hide the add-in button in outlook?

Comment: tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52817989/9468747

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently not available. The good new is the [officespdev.uservoice.com](https://officespdev.uservoice.com) has confirmation from Microsoft that the request to [allow mail apps to be OWA only](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/5129669-allow-mail-apps-to-be-owa-only) is now in backlog and there is chance it will be implemented. Obviously you are welcome to upvote this request.

Now about options available right now as work around ...

1. The suggested work around by @NamigIsmayilov ([Enable Outlook Web Add-in only on the Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45721635/enable-outlook-web-add-in-only-on-the-web/52817989#52817989)) I wouldn't consider. This is possible, but the manifest crafted this way won't be accepted by Office store.
2. You may have a look on ([How to detect if Office 365 addin is already active from a VSTO Outlook addin or vice-versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562332/how-to-detect-if-office-365-addin-is-already-active-from-a-vsto-outlook-addin-or/50570003#50570003)) thread. This is about detection from VSTO/COM add-in, if you have one, web add-in and possibility to display some informational message to the user.

Comment: it's ok for us to not have the addin in the store as we use the on-send functionality anyway. but I dont get the answer in the link that you and @NamigIsmayilov shared, moving elements out side VersionOverrides caused errors related to the schema when uploading the manifest file

Comment: @sarea You should ask this question the OP. As far as my own experience, if you won't have any `VersionOverrides` in the manifest the icon for application will shows up on the web, but not in desktop clients. You need to provide your extension points in `FormSettings` of the `OfficeApp`.